# From most frequent words how to extract technical skill words

Tags: python, nltk

I've scrape 30 job description web and stored them into a list called job_desc where each item is a job description.

```
# each item is a list of tokenized job_description
tok = [nltk.word_tokenize(job.lower()) for job in job_desc]

# ignore stop words, bullets, etc. And put it into one list
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

def clean_token(what_to_clean):
    cleaned_tok = []
    for lists in what_to_clean:
        for item in lists:
            if len(item)>2 and (item not in stop):
                cleaned_tok.append(item)
    return cleaned_tok
```

After cleaning job description I've found most frequent words using:

```
freq = nltk.FreqDist(clean_token(tok))
most_freq_words = freq.most_common(100)
```

Which outputs:

```
 [('data', 211),
 ('experience', 78),
 ('learning', 70),
 ('business', 65),
 ('team', 53),
 ('science', 51),
 ('machine', 48),.....
```

From here I only want to extract words like machine, python, C+, technical skills. How can I go about it?

Also you can see there is word "machine" showing up 48 times and I am not sure whether it is talking about machine learning how can I go about this, I know if I want to make predictions I could've used CountVectorizer and n-grams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need more than 1-word terms. Thus, it's better to go for n-grams.

Start with creating n-grams

```
import re
from nltk.util import ngrams

s = s.lower()
s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)
tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]
output = list(ngrams(tokens, 2))
```

You should get 1-gram, 2-grams and 3-grams at least to cover all possible terms.

Then you can use a [Computer Science Ontology (CSO)](https://cso.kmi.open.ac.uk/home) which includes about 14k technical terms.

An alternative would be to use their own Classifier that gets a text as input and annotate terms on it from the same ontology. You can find a demo here https://cso.kmi.open.ac.uk/classify/

When I try to classify the abstract of Machine Learning from the Wikipedia article, I get the following results

> Machine learning (ML) is the scientific study of algorithms and
>   statistical models that computer systems use to effectively perform a
>   specific task without using explicit instructions, relying on patterns
>   and inference instead. It is seen as a subset of artificial
>   intelligence. Machine learning algorithms build a mathematical model
>   based on sample data, known as "training data", in order to make
>   predictions or decisions without being explicitly programmed to
>   perform the task.[1](https://cso.kmi.open.ac.uk/classify/):2 Machine learning algorithms are used in a
>   wide variety of applications, such as email filtering, and computer
>   vision, where it is infeasible to develop an algorithm of specific
>   instructions for performing the task. Machine learning is closely
>   related to computational statistics, which focuses on making
>   predictions using computers. The study of mathematical optimization
>   delivers methods, theory and application domains to the field of
>   machine learning. Data mining is a field of study within machine
>   learning, and focuses on exploratory data analysis through
>   unsupervised learning.[3][4] In its application across business
>   problems, machine learning is also referred to as predictive
>   analytics.

- artificial intelligence
- computer systems
- computer vision
- correlation
- analysis
- data mining
- email
- inference
- machine learning
- optimization
- unsupervised learning

Comment: when using n-grams does it consider both 2 word only, when there is a word "machine learning" does it take only machine learning as two words for "machine" and "learning" separately as well so consider all 3 possibilities?

Comment: When you use 2-grams it doesn’t care about one word terms. So there isn’t “machine” on 2-grams. Just “machine learning”. To cover all the cases, calculate all 1-gram, 2-grams and 3-grams. If you believe you need to capture concepts with 4 words, go also for 4-grams.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, can we use CSO like how we use stopwords in nltk??

Comment: It’s the same idea. But I don’t think there is an implementation out of the box